# How can I check if a multipolygon can be represented as a simple polygon?

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgis-2.0

I have a large (30m+ records) spatial data set I have imported into a PostGIS database.  I did not expect to find multipolygons in the data set, but it does have a few of them.  I'd like to take a closer look at them to better understand the data I'm dealing with.  However, `shp2pgsql` indiscriminately imported everything as a multipolygon.

How can I efficiently query the dataset to filter out the multipolygons that are actually simple polygons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check and see if the number of elements is larger than one.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE ST_NumGeometries(geom) > 1;
```

If the answer is zero, create a new simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable AS 
SELECT ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)::geometry(Polygon) AS geom, attr1, attr2
FORM mytable;
```